# JPA 2 : Datastore or external database?

Tags: java, sql, google-app-engine, jpa

Hi,

I would like to get an idea about wich storing data solution to use for a medium application stored on app engine written in JAVA (jsf 2.1).
I want use use a few tables around 15, with a lot of interactions. Should I use the usual datastore with JPA 2 but without (many to many) relations or shouldd i use an eternal database storage ?

The Google cloud sql seam to be the best solution [with JPA 2](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/) to persist the data, nevertheless it's not FREE.

---

With [the datastore and JPA 2](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview?hl=fr), we can't create many to many relations, but can't we do that with 2 "one to many" relations ?
For example :

- A plane and some passengers. A plane can own many passengers, and a passenger can use many planes.
  We can translate it to the relation : **Plane many to many passengers**. And in the datastore we should store it like **PLANE one to many TICKET many to one PASSENGER**

## Thanks a lot for your answers :))

Comment: For me datastore is the right solution according that sql is payed. You can create one to many and many to one:
"The datastore can natively persist collections of simple types, including keys. This creates one approach for defining one-to-many (and many-to-many) relationships. " This is from objectify documentation. Once you understand datastore you will see how easy its for using. Try first CRUD operations with JDO to understand the basics and that convert your project to use objectify.

Comment: GAE/Datastore JDO/JPA does support unowned (normal JPA) M-N relations as their docs say. Referring to JPA1 docs doesn't help your case

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a free Java AppEngine data storage solution, seriously consider [AppEngine Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/).  And if you're open to opinions (sorry, not really on-topic on StackOverflow), my impression of JDO and JPA as abstraction layers on top of the Low Level Datastore API is that they are not worth using, especially as application complexity increases.  Read previous StackOverflow questions about these APIs to get an impression of the kinds of problems you might encounter.  At least the Low Level Datastore API gives you contact with the code that is going to eventually do the work anyway.

The hardest work in my opinion would be to redesign your application features that are based on relational assumptions (again see relevant SO questions).  You are clear that many to many relations are not feasible with Datastore.  The NoSQL approach might cause duplication of data (redundancy instead of normal form) and eventual consistency.  That might clash with your SQL expectations but don't worry, the change is worth it.  Your example of a ticket being related to a passenger and also a flight would be fine with three Kinds in the Datastore.  Move the relational constraints into the application code, for example do not delete a passenger if a ticket for that passenger exists.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer.